# Failed Postgres Replication from master to standby

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.6, barman

I have a master-standby postgres cluster; For availability issue, I want to add a new standy server.

So I created a new server, did base installation as installing postgres, creating postgres data filesystem, then initiated a pgbasebackup to the new standby (tried it many times, many from the master and many from the first standby, all failing).

> pg_basebackup -D - -h localhost -U replicator -Ft --compress=0 --progress | pigz -p $THREADS | ssh -A postgres@$TARGETDB "pigz -dc - | tar xvf - --directory=/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/"

When it finished, and I start the postgres, it fails with missing WALs and deviated timeline, though I am pretty sure these requested WALs and history file and not even there on neither the primary not the secondary.

```
2022-01-24 11:32:00 GMT [17951]: [1-1] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:  database system was interrupted while in recovery at log time 2022-01-24 11:10:02 GMT
2022-01-24 11:32:00 GMT [17951]: [2-1] user=,db=,app=,client= HINT:  If this has occurred more than once some data might be corrupted and you might need to choose an earlier recovery target.
2022-01-24 11:32:01 GMT [17951]: [3-1] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:  restored log file "00000007.history" from archive
ERROR: WAL file '00000008.history' not found in server '****' (SSH host: 10.154.129.90)
2022-01-24 11:32:01 GMT [17951]: [4-1] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:  entering standby mode
2022-01-24 11:32:02 GMT [17951]: [5-1] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:  restored log file "00000007.history" from archive
ERROR: WAL file '0000000700001C55000000F4' not found in server '****' (SSH host: 10.154.129.90)
2022-01-24 11:32:03 GMT [17951]: [6-1] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:  restored log file "0000000600001C55000000F4" from archive
ERROR: WAL file '0000000700001C55000000F3' not found in server '****' (SSH host: 10.154.129.90)
2022-01-24 11:32:04 GMT [18134]: [1-1] user=postgres,db=postgres,app=[unknown],client=[local] FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2022-01-24 11:32:04 GMT [18145]: [1-1] user=postgres,db=postgres,app=[unknown],client=[local] FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2022-01-24 11:32:04 GMT [17951]: [7-1] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:  restored log file "0000000600001C55000000F3" from archive
2022-01-24 11:32:04 GMT [17951]: [8-1] user=,db=,app=,client= FATAL:  requested timeline 7 is not a child of this server's history
2022-01-24 11:32:04 GMT [17951]: [9-1] user=,db=,app=,client= DETAIL:  Latest checkpoint is at 1C56/47CACF28 on timeline 6, but in the history of the requested timeline, the server forked off from that timeline at 1C3F/B7B96B90.
2022-01-24 11:32:04 GMT [17948]: [3-1] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:  startup process (PID 17951) exited with exit code 1
2022-01-24 11:32:04 GMT [17948]: [4-1] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
2022-01-24 11:32:04 GMT [17948]: [5-1] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Also, we have a WAL archive system to a barman server, so missing WALs during backup is not also a suspicion.

**Recovery.conf file**

```
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'user=replicator password=C0D5wallop host=$PRIMARYSERVER port=5432 sslmode=prefer sslcompression=1'
trigger_file = '/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/boo'
recovery_target_timeline='latest'
restore_command = 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no barman@$BARMANSERVER barman get-wal db-44 %f > %p'
```

Remain open for more info. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Perhaps there were some junk data left over from older attempts on Barman. Something must have archived `00000007.history` at some point.

Comment: Why is recovery_target_timeline needed?  What if you remove that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ends up that I did a **test restoration** in the past on a new **db instance**, without removing the **archive_command** in the **postgresql.conf** file, which ended up archiving that 0000007.history empty timeline.

So, when a new server was trying to fetch the archived logs from the barman, it would find that dummy timeline 0000007.history file, but without actual xlogs in the barman server, leading up to the generated error logs above.

***Solution***:

- Connect to the barman server.
- Manually moving the 0000007.history file.
- Manually removing the 00000007.history line in the xlog.db on the barman server wals/ directory.
- Restart the postgres on the secondary.

**Advise**: Take backup of anything you change in the barman server before doing it.